# Is There a way to change an attachment to a regular page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I am putting together a site in wordpress, and we want to use the gallery for a product section. The problem is, the gallery seems to only point to the attachment file for the image, and I can't seem to change anything (add meta keyword, desc, etc..)

Is there a way to just make the gallery images point to a page? or is there a way to edit the html for the pre-generated "attachment" pages?

Answer (score 0):

The `[gallery]` shortcode [can be manipulated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bgallery+%2Bshortcode). But if you want a customized attachment page, you just need the template [**`attachment.php`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Attachment_display) in your theme files.

Here's one tutorial about it: [How to Create a Custom Single Attachments Template in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-single-attachments-template-in-wordpress/).

> In this article, we will show you how to use the additional fields in the media uploader and display them in a custom single attachments template.

Comment: I may be missing something, but this doesn't seem to help me. I want to add head tags to each individual attachment post. each attachment page needs it's own tags. weather I change the tags in the attachment files individually. or I make new pages for each image, and set the gallery images to redirect to those doesn't matter as long as I can do one of them.